# Finding lim sup

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am unable to find a way to solve this. I have tried using definition of lim sup but got no where.

> Consider the series: $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\cdots$
>
> Then $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=$

Edit: This is the work I have done yesterday night. My apologies for not showing my work.

I have looked at the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$. I observed that it looks like $\frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{2^2}, \frac{2^2}{3^2},\frac{3^2}{2^3},\cdots$.

So, the general terms look like $(\frac{2}{3})^n$ for $n$ odd and $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^n$ for $n$ even.

I looked at the supremums of the tail sequences and then decided to find their infimum. The sequence as I found has $\infty$ as the supremum of each tail sequence since the sequence for $n$ even is monotonically increasing. Thus I inferred that the limsup should be $\infty$. However, the answer was given to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

This sequence I found is of course a mistake as the exponents I have taken are wrong.

The sequence actually looks like $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\cases{(\frac{2}{3})^{\frac{n+1}{2}}& n is odd\\ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^\frac{n}{2}& n is even}$

But still, the sequence of supremum of the tails consists only of $\infty$ and hence the infimum of the supremums is $\infty$. What am I missing?

Comment: It is difficult to help when you do not show any work. Like, what do you get $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ to? and does it differ on what $n$ we choose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite series and its upper and lower limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401702/infinite-series-and-its-upper-and-lower-limit)

Comment: @AndréArmatowski, I have edited the question to show my work. Please tell me what I am missing..

Comment: @Dolphin, Thank you for the link, It gave me some clarity with respect to the series. However, my real issue is that the limsup I calculated doesn't match with the answer given. Please throw some light on it.

Comment: @AchutaMuraliKarthikVankayal Dolphin's link shows you that if you let $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{3^n}$ then the limit of the ratios is $1/2$. The definition of $a_n$ was unclear and we interpreted the question different from what the author intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is perfectly fine and the "bandit" in this one is the author of the problem for making it unclear on how $a_{n}$ is to be expressed. Something I have found true for some authors is that; when in doubt a Mathematics textbook is always written in "three's".

---

If  instead of treating $a_{n}$ to be a sequence of alternating reciprocal powers of $2$ and $3$, we take $a_{n}$ to be a sequence of equal powers, as in $a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{3^{n}}$, then we get an alternate (and in hindsight a true) description of the series in question. By the following sequence of calculations we reach $\lim \sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$:

First by rewriting $a_{n}$ on a common denominator we get
$a_{n}=\frac{3^{n}+2^{n}}{6^{n}}$ and so

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{6(2^{n}+3^{n})}.$$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $3^{n+1}$ we arrive at
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1}+1}{2((\frac{2}{3})^{n}+1)}.$$
Now since
$$(\frac{2}{3})^{n},(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1}\to 0 \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty$$
we get that
$$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\lim \frac{(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1}+1}{2((\frac{2}{3})^{n}+1)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Because $\lim \sup x_{n} = \lim x_{n}$ for a sequence $x_{n}$ which converges, we can infer that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$$.